Why is w3m-mode interpreting `Page Down` incorrectly in the terminal?
In the terminal, if I describe-key in any other mode than w3m-mode, it says <prior>, but in w3m-mode it says C-[
I'm not really sure how to approach this;)

Did you try emacs -nw -Q? Does it happen there? If not, check your init file for the culprit.
